# "Drawing" Numbers on a grid using a "pencil"

Tags: c++

How do I approach this problem? The instructions are as follows:

Imagine a square grid. Now "draw" numbers (0-9) using the following commands:

- U - draw a line one square to the top
- D - draw a line one square to the bottom
- L - draw a line one square to the left
- R - draw a line one square to the right
- ^ - lift the "pencil" off the "paper"
- _ - put the "pencil" on the "paper"

Input:

first row: int N, represents the amount of numbers to check
the next N rows consist of a string which determines the order of commands
Example:

```
2
UL^D_RDLR^U
D^LLDRR_U
```

Output:

```
3 1
```

outputs a row of numbers, seperated by one space.

I hope i explained it well enough (English is not my first language).

Comment: [tag:c++] has no notion of graphics natively.

Comment: I edited it to be more clear, it doesn't actually have to be drawn, it has to recognize a pattern of commands that correspond to a number

Comment: Nothing, I can't think of anything :/

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible approach.

Convert a sequence of commands to a sequence of line segments. Have a precomputed array of line segments for each digit you must recognize. (Bear in mind that 6 and 9 can be represented in two different ways!)

Now invent a way to compare two arrays of line segments, given that

- the order of segments in a picture doesn't matter
- segment direction doesn't matter
- absolute coordinates don't matter, but relative coordinates do
- number of times a segment is drawn doesn't matter if it's greater than zero

When one needs to compare two values and some aspects of these values don't matter, the common strategy is to transform both values such that these aspects are in their *canonical form*. For example, to compare two strings when case of the characters doesn't matter, one might transform both strings to the upper case, which would be a canonical form for the purpose of case-insensitive comparison. Your task is to come up with a canonical form for each of the enumerated things that don't matter.